# How would I make a colour to an int in java?

Tags: java, minecraft

I have a piece of text that I want to make a random color. I am using the Minecraft GUI Library. Here is my code:

```
public void onEvent(event e) {
    if (e instanceof EventRender) {
        Gui.drawRect(5, 30, 70, 30 + Modules.Categories.values().length * 16 + 4, 0x90000000 );

        // Here I want random color
        Gui.drawRect(7, 33 + currentTab * 16, 9, 33 + currentTab * 16 + 12, -1);

        int count = 0;
        for(Categories c: Modules.Categories.values()) {
            fr.drawStringWithShadow(c.name, 10, 36 + count * 16, -1);
             count++;
         }

        List<Modules> modules =  Client.getModulesByCategory(Modules.Categories.values()[currentTab]);
        if(expanded) {
            if(modules.size() <= 0) 
                return;
 
        Gui.drawRect(70, 30, 70 + 68, 30 + modules.size() * 16 + 4, 0x90000000 );
        Gui.drawRect(72, 33 + category.ModuleIndex * 16, 7 + 68, 33 + category.ModuleIndex * 16 + 12, -1));
         
        for (Modules m : Client.getModulesByCategory(Modules.Categories.values()[currentTab]) ) {
            fr.drawStringWithShadow(m.name , 10 + 70, -29 + count * 16, -1);
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

That `-1` at the end of `Gui.drawRect()` method represents color which I want as random. So, I have found a random color generator here in SO. The code is `new Color((int)(Math.random() * 0x1000000))`. But when I try to plug in that piece of code in place of `-1`, it says that:

> The Super Class only accepts ints as a colour.

So is there a way I can turn that piece of code to an integer?
Full code for that class:

Comment: Is there a problem with my question. People seem to be downvoting a lot. Please give me any feed back that you have on my question

Comment: `new Color((int)(Math.random() * 0x1000000))` seems alright. You could provide more parts of your code that you have tried and getting error.

Comment: Umm, so far that is all the code I have written for that area.

Comment: Then please provide full code. At this point it is hard to debug from your statement.

Comment: I added the full class

Comment: *So is there a way I can turn that piece of code to an integer?* - I assume you are talking about the Color object which is a class in the standard JDK? Did you read the Color API for any method that returns an int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`drawRect()` method signature from Minecraft GUI library is:

> `public static void drawRect(int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int color)`

So, you can't just plug in the object from `Color` class in place of `int color` argument. In this case, you could simply use only `(int)(Math.random() * 0x1000000)` without creating a `Color` object. So, the part of your code should look like this:

```
Gui.drawRect(7, 33 + currentTab * 16, 9, 33 + currentTab * 16 + 12, (int)(Math.random() * 0x1000000));
```

Comment: @webetreesorg *Thanks, that worked!* - maybe, but it doesn't answer your question. Your question was "How to make a Color into a int". What happens if you only have access to a Color object? How would you solve the problem. So I will ask you again - how about reading the Color API for an appropriat method? Did that work?

Comment: @camickr Maybe the title set by OP is wrong, but the context mentioned in the body is different. The API that was used in question body, that doesn't use object from `Color`. After searching about the random color, maybe OP went through the SO post that uses `Color` and thought it could be used. But `Color` class has no effect in this context.

So, more or less, this answers the OP's original problem, but maybe not the title.

Comment: I know it doesn't use a Color object. The point of my comment is to get the OP to think before posting a question. You can't program without reading the API. If the OP took a couple of minutes to read the Color API they would find a method that returns the int value of a Color object. Maybe the OP decides they don't want a random color but wants to use Color.RED. How to you get the int value of that? By reading the API and understanding the methods of the API you don't limit yourself to solution that only works in a special situation, which is what this answer does.

Comment: Oh. I've understood your intention now. Thanks for clarifying.